Keycloak Create User timestamps not read only
When creating or updating a user via the Keycloak UI Users / User details screen, the timestamps are not locked as read-only and do not display in a standard human-readable format. Is this a bug? Is there something I can fix in the UI?

We are running one of the latest builds, 25.0.1.

This is not the place to report bugs in software. Try to find if they have a place to submit bugs.
